# Script working fine while it should raise NameError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Below is a working minipart of the whole script, only necessary parts. In the steps below I explained how the input works(If you want to run the program) because I'm using a library that detects when the user press 'ENTER'(**the library is 'pynput'**). Just in case, if it's relevant with this problem. **Do the steps in exact order** if you want to run the program correctly.

Problematic part is at the end of the script. If you run this script, do below and you'll see this printed in the console: `"I'M A PRINT FUNCTION WORKING FINE"` just before these lines;

`print (list(y))`

`del list(y)[0]`

`print (type(y))`

**which is where my problem starts.** It **does not** raise any error(**I expect there should be NameError: name 'y' is not defined**), it does not close the PyQt5 window or respond anything while **'y' *is not defined anywhere* in the whole script.** I put there **a test button** to show that program working fine after this part.

Why it doesn't raise any error while 'y' is not defined anywhere, OR atleast close the main window of PyQt5? It's like it ignores it and keep working, no respond at all.

Am I missing something here or is there something I don't know about how PyQt5 main loop works?

***Steps for input if you want to run the program correctly***

To input in the first QLineEdit(**Next to 'SET' label**), for example;

1- Press 'a'

2- Press Enter

3- Press 'b'

4- Press Enter

5- Press Enter

To input in the second QLineEdit(**Next to 'TOP' label**), for example;

1- Press 'a'

2- Press Enter

3- Press Enter

4- Press 'a'

5- Press Enter

6- Press 'b'

7- Press Enter

8- Press Enter

9- Press Enter

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from itertools import combinations

import sys
import re

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        ##BELOW DETECTS WHEN THE USER PRESS ENTER
        self.listener = Listener(on_press=self.on_press)
        self.listener.start()                               
        self.listener1 = Listener(on_press=self.on_press_top)

        ##CENTERING THE SCREEN
        def center(self):
            qr = QMainWindow.frameGeometry()
            cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
            qr.moveCenter(cp)
            self.move(qr.topLeft())

        ##JUST GUI
        self.setWindowTitle("Foo")
        self.setFixedSize(950, 710)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(119,136,153)")
        QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)

        ##SET -LINE EDIT
        self.kume_edit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.kume_edit.setText("{")
        self.kume_edit.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{ background-color: orange; color: blue; font: 11 }")

        fnt = self.kume_edit.font()
        fnt.setPointSize(15)
        self.kume_edit.setFont(fnt)
        self.kume_edit.setGeometry(140, 300, 300, 30)
        ##

        ##SET -LABEL
        self.kume_label = QLabel(self)
        self.kume_label.setText("SET:")
        self.kume_label.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{ background-color: orange; color: blue; font: 11 }")

        fnt1 = self.kume_label.font()
        fnt1.setPointSize(15)
        self.kume_label.setFont(fnt1)
        self.kume_label.setGeometry(50, 300, 60, 32)
        ##

        ##TOPOLOGY -LINE EDIT
        self.top_edit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.top_edit.setText("{{")
        self.top_edit.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{ background-color: orange; color: blue; font: 11 }")

        fnt2 = self.top_edit.font()
        fnt2.setPointSize(15)
        self.top_edit.setFont(fnt2)
        self.top_edit.setGeometry(140, 400, 300, 30)
        ##

        ##TOPOLOGY -LABEL
        self.topo_label = QLabel(self)
        self.topo_label.setText("TOP:")
        self.topo_label.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{ background-color: orange; color: blue; font: 11 }")

        fnt3 = self.topo_label.font()
        fnt3.setPointSize(15)
        self.topo_label.setFont(fnt3)
        self.topo_label.setGeometry(50, 400, 80, 32)
        ##

        ##FUNCTION CHANGES THIS LABEL WHEN THE DESIRED CONDITION OCCURS
        self.top_label = QLabel(self)
        fnt4 = self.top_label.font()
        fnt4.setPointSize(15)
        self.top_label.setFont(fnt4)
        self.top_label.setGeometry(140, 450, 900, 30)
        ##

        ##BUTTON SHOWS THAT THE PROGRAM WORKING FINE
        ##CLICK THIS BUTTON BEFORE AND AFTER YOU RUN
        but = QPushButton(self)
        but.setGeometry(500,400,50,50)
        but.setText("Click Me")
        but.clicked.connect(self.but_test)
        self.count_test = 0
        ##

        self.top_ = 0
        self.kord_ = 300

        self.show()

    def but_test(self):             #########CLICK THIS BUTTON
        self.count_test += 1        #########TO SEE THAT ITS WORKING AFTER 'print(type(y))' PART
        self.top_label.setText("The program working fine {}".format(self.count_test))

    def on_press(self,key): #########THIS DETECTS WHEN THE USER PRESS "ENTER" IN 'SET QLINEEDIT'

        if key == Key.enter:


            if self.kume_edit.text()[-1] == ",":
                self.kume_edit.setText(self.kume_edit.text()[:-1] + "}")
                self.kume_edit.setReadOnly(True)
                self.listener1.start()
                self.listener.stop()

            else:
                self.kume_edit.setText(self.kume_edit.text() + ",")


    def on_press_top(self,key): #########THIS DETECTS WHEN THE USER PRESS "ENTER" IN 'TOPOLOGY QLINEEDIT'

        if key == Key.enter:
            self.top_ += 15

            if self.top_ > 220:
                self.kord_ += 15
                self.top_edit.setGeometry(140, 400, self.kord_, 30)

            if self.top_edit.text()[-1] == "{":
                self.top_edit.setText(self.top_edit.text()[:-2])
                self.top_edit.setText(self.top_edit.text() + "}")
                self.top_edit.setReadOnly(True)

                self.top_edit.setGeometry(140, 400, self.kord_, 30)

                self.topoloji_mi()  #####################HERE THE FUNCTION IS CALLED - ONLY HERE

                self.listener1.stop()

            elif self.top_edit.text()[-1] == ",":
                self.top_edit.setText(self.top_edit.text()[:-1] + "}")
                self.top_edit.setText(self.top_edit.text() + ",")
                self.top_edit.setText(self.top_edit.text() + "{")

            else:
                self.top_edit.setText(self.top_edit.text() + ",")


    def kumetop(self): #############THIS JUST RETURNS TWO LISTS
        reg = r"\{(.*?)\}"
        matches = re.findall(reg, self.top_edit.text()[1:-1])

        top_set = []
        top_set.append(set())
        for x in matches:
            top_set.append(set(x.split(",")))

        kume_set = []
        for x in self.kume_edit.text():
            if x.isalnum():
                kume_set.append(set(x.split(",")))
        return kume_set,top_set

    def topoloji_mi(self): #################PROB FUNCTION #######################################
        kume_set,top_set = self.kumetop() ###TAKING THE LISTS


        for x in combinations(top_set, 2):

            ################WHATS THIS
            print ("IM A PRINT FUNCTION WORKING FINE") ###THIS PRINT WORKS
            print(list(y))
            del list(y)[0]               #######PYCHARM RAISE NO ERROR, WINDOW IS ALSO WORKING
            print (type(y))              ###CLICK THE TEST BUTTON

            if len(z) == len(list(y)) and all([z.count(i) == list(y).count(i) for i in kume_set]):
                self.top_label.setText("BLABLABLA")
                print("IM NOT WORKING")



    def close_application(self):
        sys_exit()

def run():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Comment: why do you expect `list(y)` not to raise a name error, but you expect `del list(y)[0]` to?

Comment: But anyway, I suspect that somewhere in the three different modules you used `*` imports from, there is a `y` defined. This is precisely the reason you should never use starred imports.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga hmm, well that could be right, but I don't think in a library like PyQt they will just define a variable called 'y'?

Comment: You can easily find this out. Just have an empty file with those started imports and `print(y); print(type(y))`

Comment: Surely it's totally redundant to use `pynput` in a pyqt program? I suspect the problem is that `pynput` runs in a separate thread, and you are therefore trying to perform gui operations *outside the main thread*, which qt does not support at all. Get rid of `pynput` and use the keyboard and mouse facilities provided by pyqt.

Comment: Well, besides pynput, I couldn't find a way to detect if the user presses Enter in a QLineEdit or not. So using pynput

Comment: @GLHF Detecting an enter keypresses is easy to do in a line-edit (or any other widget). There is no need to use `pynput` at all. All you need to do is override `mousePressEvent` or use an event-filter. There are dozens of examples showing how to do this on SO and elsewhere.